# Neovim wont match beginning of word with # sign

Tags: neovim, regular-expression, search

`/\<` matches beginning of all words as expected.

`/\<a` matches beginning of all words starting with `a`

but `/\<#` doesn't match words starting with `#`

what am I missing here?

Was planning on using this search pattern to navigate sections in a markdown document.

Comment: See `:help /\<` and look at the mention of `'iskeyword'`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Ben the problem you have is that '#' is probably not in `iskeyword` and the  `#` is not a word boundary.

You can fake it:

```
/\v(^|\s)\zs#
```

or if you would like to avoid the `\v` magic flag:

```
/\(^\|\s\)\zs#
```

Explanation:

- `(^|\s)` match either the beginning of the line
- `^` or a space (e.g. `' '` or `<tab>`)
- `\zs` set the beginning of the match
- `#` match `#`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the `/\<` pattern then uses the `iskeyword` option.

solved the issue by automatically adding `#` to `iskeyword` automatically on opening markdown documents, by adding this to my vimrc:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.md setlocal iskeyword+=#
```

see also this reddit post:
https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/w2uco4/vim_wont_match_beginning_of_word_followed_by/

Comment: You probably want to use put `setlocal iskeyword+=#` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim` (or your neovim equivalent).